# Bypass shadow-root with selenium on python

Tags: python, selenium, shadow-dom

I am having issues bypassing the shadow_root in a [website](https://betfury.io/sport-betting?bt-path=%2F5%2F1669817298497703936%2F1710865662831894528%2F2107904491658551296). The code I was using worked a few months ago, but is not working now (have tried using different versions of Selenium).

First things first should I be getting this return with my code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="bt-inner-page"]')
shadow_section = select_shadow_element_by_css_selector("#bt-inner-page")
shadow_section
```

Return: **{'shadow-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '7406d51b-bb21-43ae-be37-1583e7e6255c'}**

As when I run the next line of code:

```
shadow_section.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[data-editor-id='verticalNavbarEventPlate']")
```

I get this error: **'dict' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_css_selector'**

So what do you think is the issue with my code?

Comment: _trying to bypass_: What is the actual manual step to bypass the shadow_root section? Clicking on some element? Which element?

Comment: Instead of comments, please update the main question will the additional info.

Comment: Have just edited the code. The last line of code is the element I want to click on.

Comment: Whom do you feel would debug your code to find the exact element, if not you?

Comment: I'm looking on here for help with debugging to be honest

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?